# bound target control not updating when source changed programatically

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps

I have 2 "textboxes" both bound to a source string property with "mode =2way". When i change the text in one, the other changes perfectly . But when i change the source string programmatically neither gets updated. I cant figure out what i am missing. Here is my code snippets:

Xaml code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <local:x/>
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
<Button Content="Reset"  Click="Button_Click"/>
```

button click handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    obj = new x() { Text="reset success"};
}
```

object class:

```
class x:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set 
        { 
            text = value;
            OnPropertyChange("Text");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedEvent = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChangedEvent != null)
        {
            propertyChangedEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i found a workaround any way by setting datacontext of stackpanel in code

Comment: Please check an answer or add more help to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a new object. That is the reason. Dont make a new object just cast and change the actual binded object's content(Text).

When you make a new object, the "subcription" is lost in your solution. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <local:x/>
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

XAML excerpt above means : set `DataContext` of stackpanel to a new instance of class `x`. Because instantiation done by XAML, you don't have reference to that `x` instance until you get it from stackpanel's `DataContext`.

And if you want to test whether your data-binding works or not, you should modify existing instance of class `x` (which is currently set as `DataContext`).

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var currentDataContext = (x)myStackPanel.DataContext;
    x.Text = "reset success";
}
```

If you want to set `StackPanel`'s `DataContext` from code as stated in comment, it is save to remove `DataContext` setting part in XAML.

Comment: I still didnt understand the behaviour. I am sure the binding works as whatever i type in the first textbox shows up in the second,but when i use the button to reset both ,nothin happens....

Comment: yes, the binding works, both textboxes bound to same `x` instance. But on button click, you're resetting a new instance of `x` class, not the one those textboxes already bound to.